# HTML Service and Forms

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use HTML Service and in particular a HTML form.
I have my sumbit button inside complex  html structure. How i can sobstitute the line:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit"
          onclick="google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler(returnFunctionHandler)
              .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
```

this.parentNode it isn't the Node form element.

Right now, nothing is passed to the ProcessForm apps script function and it seems that is not running at all.

Thank you in advance

```
<script>
      function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
      }
    </script>
    <form id="myForm">
    <fieldset style="width: 0px; border-color: #0000FF;">
    <legend style="color: #0000FF; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; width:400px">Inserimento richiesta</legend>
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Data*:</td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Richiedente*:</td>
    <td>
    <select style="width:150px;">
    <? 
    var data=recuperaDati("idSSRichiedenti");
    for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    ?>
    <option value <?=data[j][1]?>><?= data[j][0]?></option>
    <? } 
    ?>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    <?//tipologia?>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Tipologia*:</td>
    <td>
    <select style="width:150px;">
    <? 
    var data=recuperaDati("idssTipologia");
    for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    ?>
    <option value <?=data[j][0]?>><?= data[j][0]?></option>
    <? } 
    ?>
    </select></td>
    </tr>

    <?//livelli di urgenza?>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Livelli di urgenza*:</td>
    <td>
    <select style="width:150px;">
    <? 
    var data=recuperaDati("idssLivelliUrgenza");
    for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    ?>
    <option value <?=data[j][0]?>><?= data[j][0]?></option>
    <? } 
    ?>
    </select style="width:150px;"></td>
    </tr>

    <?//Reparti?>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Reparto*:</td>
    <td>
    <select style="width:150px;">
    <? 
    var data=recuperaDati("idssReparti");
    for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    ?>
    <option value <?=data[j][0]?>><?= data[j][0]?></option>
    <? } 
    ?>
    </select></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Cognome:</td><td><input type="text" name="cognome" size="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">E-mail:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" size="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Allegati:</td><td><input name="myFile" type="file"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td><td style="float:right;">
      <input type="button" value="Submit"
          onclick="google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler(returnFunctionHandler)
              .processForm(this.parentNode)" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>     
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById('myForm')` to retrieve the element of your form.

So :

```
<input type="button" value="Submit"
          onclick="google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler(returnFunctionHandler)
              .processForm(document.getElementById('myForm'))" />
```

Comment: Hello Davinov, i have tryed to sobstitute many times with that code but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit"
          onclick="google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler(returnFunctionHandler)
              .processForm(this.parentNode.parentNode
                .parentNode.parentNode.parentNode)" />
```

(if I just counted the right number of parents up to the form tag).

Not very nice to see and hard to modify, but it worked for me in a similar case with only two levels. Didn't test your code, though.

Regards.